# Column does not exist in query of multiple CTEs

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is the table that I have created from when running the 1st CTE.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fce856

```
WITH calling_time AS
  (SELECT fe.date
          , ti.call_time
          , ti.call_duration
          count(DISTINCT user_id) AS CALLED
   FROM call_log clo
   INNER JOIN loging fe 
         ON clo.user_id= fe.id
   INNER JOIN loging_communication ti 
         ON fe.user_id= ti.id
   WHERE clo.date_call >= dateadd(DAY, -90, getdate())::date
   GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
  )
```

With below results

```
Date           call_time         call_duration
2011-10-01         60                 30
2011-10-01         60                 15
2015-10-01        180                 30
2005-10-05         30                 45
2020-02-03         90                 30
2020-05-03         15                 15
2020-07-03         30                 15
2005-02-26         30                 15
2011-10-01         60                 30
2010-10-01         60                 30
2007-02-03         90                 30
2018-05-31         90                 30
2002-09-31         90                 30
2009-11-31         90                 30
```

The goal is to create a new column out the first CTE (table above) called `count_duration` that show for instance a 60 `call_time` slot they were 3 people who had a 30 min `call_duration` or for a 90 `call_time` slow they were 5 people who had a 30 call duration and the table would look like this:

```
 Date           call_time       call_duration  combine_time    total_call
 2011-10-01         60                 30       60_30                3
 2007-02-03         90                 30       90_30                2
 2005-02-26         30                 15       30_15                2
 2015-10-01        180                 30       180_30               1
 2005-10-05         30                 45       30_45                1
 2020-02-03         90                 30       90_30                5
 2020-05-03         15                 15        15_15               1
```

When writing my full CTE query, for some reason I got an error that `b.class` doesn't exist. The first CTE creates the first table and the goal is for the query below to create my final my output:

```
WITH calling_time AS
  (SELECT fe.date
          , ti.call_time
          , ti.call_duration
          , count(DISTINCT user_id) AS CALLED
   FROM call_log clo
   INNER JOIN loging fe 
         ON clo.user_id = fe.id
   INNER JOIN loging_communication ti 
         ON fe.user_id = ti.id
   WHERE clo.date_call >= dateadd(DAY, -90, getdate())::date
   GROUP BY 1, 2, 3),
     look_up AS
  (SELECT MAX(date) date
         , a.call_time
         , a.call_duration
         , cast(a.call_time AS varchar(10)) +
           '_' + 
           cast(a.call_duration AS varchar(10)) combine_time
         , b.count[total_call]
   FROM calling_time a
   INNER JOIN
     (SELECT call_time
             , call_duration
             , count(*) COUNT
      FROM calling_time
      GROUP BY call_time,
               call_duration) b 
     ON a.call_time = b.call_time
     AND a.call_duration = b.call_duration
   GROUP BY a.call_time
            , a.call_duration
            , b.count)

SELECT * FROM look_up
```

Comment: According to the query `b` only has three columns: `call_time`, `call_duration`, and `count`. Where's the `class` column supposed to come from?

Comment: Maybe you meant `b.count AS total_call`? If so, this can just be a typo. Square brackets are not used in Postgres for column identifiers. Also, heed [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). Finally, if final query is simply `SELECT * FROM cte`. Just use last cte as outermost query.